# Why isn't opacity and list reordering working with react-dnd and react-virtualization?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-virtualized, react-dnd

I'm trying to set up a react-dnd sortable list inside a react-virtualized `List`. The example I'm working from with react-dnd is here:

https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/examples-sortable-simple.html

I've got it mostly working, but when I drag an item around, items that I'm hovering over don't adjust their opacity and reorder correctly.

[image]

Compare that to the example from react-dnd:[image]

I've made an example project that demonstrates the problem (https://github.com/ericdcobb/virtual-drag-n-drop), but will paste the code here. This is the DragDropContext:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {List} from 'react-virtualized';
import {name} from 'faker';
import Item from './Item.js';
import {DragDropContext} from 'react-dnd';
import HTML5Backend from 'react-dnd-html5-backend';
import update from 'react/lib/update';

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        const items = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i += 1) {
            const item = {
                id: i,
                text: name.findName()
            };
            items[i] = item;
        }

        this.state = {
            items: items
        }
        this.rowRenderer = this.rowRenderer.bind(this);
        this.moveItem = this.moveItem.bind(this);
    }

    moveItem(dragIndex, hoverIndex) {
        const {items} = this.state;
        const dragItem = items[dragIndex];
        this.setState(update(this.state, {
            items: {
                $splice: [
                    [
                        dragIndex, 1
                    ],
                    [hoverIndex, 0, dragItem]
                ]
            }
        }));
    }

    rowRenderer(row) {
        const {items} = this.state;
        const item = items[row.index]

        return (<Item index={row.index} key={row.key} style={row.style} item={item} moveItem={this.moveItem}/>);
    }

    render() {
        const {items} = this.state;
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <List className="list-group" width={800} items={items} height={1000} rowCount={items.length} rowHeight={55} rowRenderer={this.rowRenderer}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default DragDropContext(HTML5Backend)(App);
```

And the DragSource/DragTarget:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {DragSource, DropTarget} from 'react-dnd';
import { findDOMNode } from 'react-dom';
import _ from 'lodash';

const ItemSource = {
    beginDrag(props) {
        return {id: props.item.id,
        index: props.index};
    }
};

const ItemTarget = {
    hover(props, monitor, component) {
        const dragIndex = monitor.getItem().index;
        const hoverIndex = props.index;

        // Don't replace items with themselves
        if (dragIndex === hoverIndex) {
            return;
        }

        // Determine rectangle on screen
        const hoverBoundingRect = findDOMNode(component).getBoundingClientRect();

        // Get vertical middle
        const hoverMiddleY = (hoverBoundingRect.bottom - hoverBoundingRect.top) / 2;

        // Determine mouse position
        const clientOffset = monitor.getClientOffset();

        // Get pixels to the top
        const hoverClientY = clientOffset.y - hoverBoundingRect.top;

        // Only perform the move when the mouse has crossed half of the items height
        // When dragging downwards, only move when the cursor is below 50%
        // When dragging upwards, only move when the cursor is above 50%

        // Dragging downwards
        if (dragIndex < hoverIndex && hoverClientY < hoverMiddleY) {
            return;
        }

        // Dragging upwards
        if (dragIndex > hoverIndex && hoverClientY > hoverMiddleY) {
            return;
        }

        // Time to actually perform the action
        props.moveItem(dragIndex, hoverIndex);

        // Note: we're mutating the monitor item here!
        // Generally it's better to avoid mutations,
        // but it's good here for the sake of performance
        // to avoid expensive index searches.
        monitor.getItem().index = hoverIndex;
    }
};

function collect(connect, monitor) {
    return {connectDragSource: connect.dragSource(), isDragging: monitor.isDragging()}
}

function connect(connect, monitor) {
    return {connectDropTarget: connect.dropTarget()}
}

class Item extends Component {

    render() {
        let self = this;
        const {connectDragSource, isDragging, connectDropTarget, style} = self.props;

        const opacity = isDragging
            ? 0
            : 1;

        return connectDragSource(connectDropTarget(
            <div key={self.props.key} style={{...style, opacity}} className="Item">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-10">{self.props.item.text}</div>

                </div>
            </div>
        ));
    }
}

//TODO constant for this first string
export default _.flow([
    DragSource('item', ItemSource, collect),
    DropTarget('item', ItemTarget, connect)
])(Item);
```

I am trying to get the items to flow around the dragged item, as they do in the example. It seems like in my implementation, the wrong item is becoming opaque and it is failing to shift up or down.

Apologies for some of the vague words here, I guess dragging and dropping stuff around the screen is difficult to talk about, hopefully the code and screenshots help explain my problem.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with react-dnd to be able to answer your question without a lot of digging in. I will recommend clauderic/react-sortable-hoc though as working nicely with react-virtualized. It's really easy to integrate. Not sure if it's an option for what you're doing but wanted to mention it in case.

Comment: @brianvaughn I'll take a look, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

I know this super later respond, but I figure out that some people might have this problem when they creating DnD List

In order this work correctly you need to pass `id` to the `item` (or `card` - it depends how you name your item)

So you have to do something like this:

```js
<DndCard
  id={item.id}
  key={item.id}
  state={hiddenColumnState}
  dispatch={hiddenDispatch}
  index={index}
  canDrag={!locked.includes(item)}
>
  {i18n.t(`UI.${item}`)}
  {isLocked(item)}
</DndCard>
```

**NOTE**: do not use index as a key because it cannot tell if item is uniq or not.

Eventually you going to put id into the drag:

```js
  const [ dragProps, connectDrag ] = useDrag({
    item: {
      id, // magic is here
      type: state.type,
      index,
      items: state.items,
      indexMemo: index,
      item: state.items[ index ],
    },
    collect: monitor => ({
      isDragging: monitor.isDragging(),
    }),
  });
```

For more info, you can refer to official example that was made by `react-dnd` [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/react-dnd/react-dnd/tree/gh-pages/examples_hooks_js/04-sortable/simple?from-embed)